# How can I create select statement on this two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

How can I create sql statement on this, to output like this, I tried inner join but I could not get the name of p_id in usertable.

```
user_id         user_name       p_name                pid

1               millan          null                   

5               jane            millan                 1

6               lester          millan                 1

7               miller          jane                   5

8               jamie           jane                   5
```

here is my table.
**gather_table**

```
p_id        u_id
null         1

1            5

1            6

5            7

5            8
```

**user table**

```
user_id      user_name

1            millan

2            john

3            max

4            chris

5            jane

6            lester

7            miller

8            jamie
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do the id values in p_id and u_id relate? They seem to both link to the user table, but the exact way isn't clear.

Comment: you can use select in select query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u1.user_id, u1.user_name, u2.user_name AS p_name, u2.user_id AS pid
FROM gather_table g 
LEFT JOIN user_table u1 ON g.u_id = u1.user_id 
LEFT JOIN user_table u2 ON g.p_id = u2.user_id
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to join the `user table` two times to get the names

```
select
g.u_id,
u1.user_name,
u2.user_name as p_name,
g.p_id as pid
from gather_table g
left join user u1 on u1.user_id = g.u_id
left join user u2 on u2.user_id = g.p_id
```

Comment: I get null for p_name

Comment: sorry i had a typo i fixed it.

Comment: it works now,I will just give you points I already accepted answers, it works too.